# Does the Security Key C NFC from Yubico support Fido2 largeBlob extension, using the browser?

Tags: webauthn, yubico, yubikey, passkey

I would like to use a Security Key C NFC with Fido2 largeBlobs
https://docs.yubico.com/yesdk/users-manual/application-fido2/large-blobs.html

According to the documentation, the device should support it. The Security Key C NFC supports FIDO2/WebAuth.

I am using Chrome for testing which supports largeBlob extensions, I tested it using the Virtual Authentication Environment and it works as intended.

I am using @simplewebauthn/browser and server for the relying party.

However when I connect my Yubi Key, largeBlob is not supported.

Here is my authenticatorSelection I use when I start registering the key:

```
{
    "residentKey": "required",
    "userVerification": "required",
    "requireResidentKey": true
}
```

The extensions I need:

```
{
    "largeBlob": {
        "support": "preferred"
    },
    "credProps": true
}
```

And what I received back from the authenticator, largeBlob is not supported...

```
{
    "credProps": {
        "rk": true
    },
    "largeBlob": {
        "supported": false
    }
}
```

The browser does support it else the largeBlob key in the object would be undefined, but seems like the Yubi key doesn't?

The demo for largeBlobs also doesn't work https://webauthn-large-blob.glitch.me/ as it fails to store the blob.

Answer (score 0):

LargeBlob is a fairly new extension, so it will only be implemented by recently manufactured security keys.

You can check if a security key supports largeBlob using the [fido2-token](https://developers.yubico.com/libfido2/Manuals/fido2-token.html) tool:

```
$ fido2-token -I ioreg://4295240530 | grep largeBlobs
options: rk, up, uv, noplat, uvToken, alwaysUv, credMgmt, authnrCfg, bioEnroll, clientPin, largeBlobs, pinUvAuthToken, setMinPINLength, nomakeCredUvNotRqd, credentialMgmtPreview, userVerificationMgmtPreview​
```

One security key that supports largeBlobs is the [YubiKey Bio](https://www.yubico.com/products/yubikey-bio-series/).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Chrome on macOS or Linux, you can also do any operation with the security key from the browser and see the transcript on chrome://device-log. One of the responses from the security key will be its getInfo, which will contain the list of extensions. So, if you don't see the string `largeBlob` on that page, then it doesn't support it.

Note that largeBlob has a very specific use. If you're looking to store/encrypt data, you probably want the [PRF extension](https://w3c.github.io/webauthn/#prf-extension).